# pyldavis Unable to view the graph

Tags: python-3.x, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to visually depict my topics in python using pyldavis. However i am unable to view the graph. Is it that we have to view the graph in the browser or will it get popped upon execution. Below is my code

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim as gensimvis
print('Pyldavis ....')
vis_data = gensimvis.prepare(ldamodel, doc_term_matrix, dictionary)
pyLDAvis.display(vis_data)
```

The program is continuously in execution mode on executing the above commands. Where should I view my graph? Or where it will be stored? Is it integrated only with the Ipython notebook?Kindly guide me through this. 
P.S My python version is 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

This not work:

`pyLDAvis.display(vis_data)`

This will work for you:

`pyLDAvis.show(vis_data)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem now.
EDIT:
My script looks as follows:

first part:

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.sklearn
print('start script')
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(strip_accents = 'unicode',stop_words = 'english',lowercase = True,token_pattern = r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b',max_df = 0.5,min_df = 10)
dtm_tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(docs_raw)
lda_tf = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=20, learning_method='online')
print('fit')
lda_tf.fit(dtm_tf)
```

second part:

```
print('prepare')
vis_data = pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare(lda_tf, dtm_tf, tf_vectorizer)
print('display')
pyLDAvis.display(vis_data)
```

The problem is in the line "vis_data = (...)".if I run the script, it will print 'prepare' and keep on running after that without printing anything else (so it never reaches the line "print('display')).

Funny thing is, when I just run the whole script it gets stuck on that line, but when I run the first part, got to my console and execute purely the single line "vis_data = pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare(lda_tf, dtm_tf, tf_vectorizer)" this is executed in a couple of seconds.

As for the graph, I saved it as html ("simple") and use the html file to view the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (I use PyCharm as IDE) The problem is that pyLDAvize is developed for Ipython (see the docs, https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pyldavis/latest/pyldavis.pdf, page 3). 
My fix/workaround:

- make a dict of lda_tf, dtm_tf, tf_vectorizer (eg., pyLDAviz_dict)dump the dict to a file (eg mydata_pyLDAviz.pkl)
- read the pkl file into notebook (I did get some depreciation info from pyLDAviz, but that had no effect on the end result)
- play around with pyLDAviz in notebook
- if you're happy with the view, dump it into html

The cause is (most likely) that pyLDAviz expects continuous user interaction (including user-initiated "exit"). However, I rather dump data from a smart IDE and read that into jupyter, than develop/code in jupyter notebook. That's pretty much like going back to before-emacs times.

From experience this approach works quite nicely for other plotting rountines

Answer (score -1):

If you received the module error `pyLDA.gensim`, then try this one instead:

```
import pyLdAvis.gensim_models
```

You get the error because of a new version update.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning what version(s) are relevant to the suspected error and your solution.